# Using JS/jQuery to do string search/fuzzy matching?

Tags: javascript, jquery

entirely in JS, no server backend. I need to allow the user to search and then show a list of matched names. I'm using jQuery UI AutoComplete but need some JS to filter the results.

Given an Array of names:

```
Bob Hope
James Jones
Steve Jobs
Larry McBridge
```

Given a search term like  Bo

How can I get just Bob Hope to return

Given a Search term like b:

How can I get all but James Jones?

Any simple JS for comparing two strings? Thanks

Comment: For the benefit of future readers, I have implemented a library just for this: http://github.com/uohzxela/fuzzy-autocomplete

Comment: @uohzxela - For the benefit of myself, I came here to **avoid** using a library (had enough of those). Also, a quick glance at yours hits it was made for a very specific use-case and it's unlikely to help many devs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var names = ["Bob Hope","James Jones","Steve Jobs","Larry McBridge"]   
var query = "bo"
var results = $(names)
        .map(function(i,v){ 
            if(v.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase())!=-1){return v} 
        }).get()

// results is ["Bob Hope"]
```

Comment: So to test a single string if(stringToSearch.toLowerCase().indexOf(stringQuery.toLowerCase())!=-1){ alert("match"); }

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I misunderstood you (given the complexity of the above answer), but I came up with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/HJQsp/) which uses jQuery. Every time a key is pressed (when the input has focus), it searches all `li` elements on the page and finds whether they contain the search term.

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul><li>Bob Hope</li>
<li>James Jones</li>
<li>Steve Jobs</li>
<li>Larry McBridge</li></ul><br>
Search: <input id="search" length="24" />
```

And here is your jQuery:

```
$("#search").keyup(function(){
    $("li").hide();
   var term = $(this).val();
    $("li:contains('" + term + "')").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Ivan's answer, but with ES6 changes:

```
var names = ["Bob Hope","James Jones","Steve Jobs","Larry McBridge"];

function findIn(s, list){
    return list.filter((v) => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(s.toLowerCase()) != -1 );
}


findIn('bo', names);
```